# Top articles with unique name

Tags: sql, dql

I need to select top rated articles with uniqune name. I've got this articles table:

```
id     name   
---------------
1    Article 1 
2    Article 1
3    Article 2
```

and votes table:

```
article_id   rating
-------------------- 
   1           3
   1           2
   3           1
```

When I group articles by name, it counts average from rating even of articles with same name.

```
SELECT article.name, AVG(vote.rating) rating
FROM article
LEFT JOIN vote ON vote.article_id = article.id
GROUP BY article.name
```

but I want to get average rating of just top rated articles. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you for any advice.

EDIT:
I want to get this result:

```
    name       average_rating
   --------------------------
   Article 1   2.5
   Article 2   1
```

Comment: If you are averaging then top rating means what? Is it based on some constant or top from the table data only?

Comment: Can you post the desired result that you want?

Comment: It's is based on table data. I've edited the question.

Comment: @DrahomírHanák I am unsure what the issue is, your query returns the desired result -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bb9f/3

Comment: @bluefeet Yes but I want the same result event if I vote for the second article - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31b18/1/0 - now I have average rating of both articles with name "Article1", but it should return average rating of the best one (with the highest rating)

Comment: @DrahomírHanák Do you want to return the article that has been voted on the most?

Comment: @bluefeet Yes I do. But all unique articles. For example "Article 1" is two times in database so I want to return just that who has been voted on the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was lookig for:

```
SELECT result.id, result.name, result.rating
FROM (
    SELECT article.id AS id, article.name AS name, AVG(vote.rating) AS rating
    FROM article 
    LEFT JOIN vote ON vote.article_id = article.id
    GROUP BY article.id
    ORDER BY rating DESC
) AS result
GROUP BY result.name
```

Probably, it can be handled better but this just works. Thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried grouping by the article_id instead?

Comment: Yes, I have. It selects all articles. Event those with same name.

Answer (score 0):

You should be grouping by Article Id instead, as it shall be unique for each one of them

```
SELECT article.name, AVG(vote.rating) rating
FROM article
LEFT JOIN vote ON vote.article_id = article.id
GROUP BY article.id
```